# What is the correct syntax for update TimeStamp column in PostgreSQL with Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I want update my timestamp column on PostgreSQL with this :

```
    function updateStatusCreated(request, response, next) {
  const date_generation_file = new Date();
  pool.query(
    `UPDATE data
        SET report_status = 'CREATED', date_generation = '${date_generation_file}'`
  ),
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) {
        return next(error);
      }
      return response.status(200).json(results);
    };
  return next();
}
```

But i receive this error message :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: syntax error at or near "'Tue Oct 19 2021 14:19:29 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)'"
```

The parameters of the column are "timestamp with timezone"

Comment: maybe you forgot to add the field name you want to update before ${date_generation_file} like report_date =

Comment: Frist of all you are missing date column name in your query. Besides that If you are going to be using current datetime, you should be using postgres built in function 'NOW()'. For example: "CREATED_AT"=now().

Comment: Thank U it's correct I did not know this function!

Answer (score -1):

The perfect choice is to use [Sequelize ORM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize)

Comment: Reason it's "perfect"?   Can you include specifics regarding "update my timestamp column on PostgreSQL" using this tool?